# Passing custom data in List in react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I am having the data in the component and want to send the data in the `[List][1]` component of react-admin.
Is there a way to send the data in List Component like

```
<List { ...props } data={listData} />
```

The data comes from an API that is called on the basis of another one(The API is dependent). So, I cannot call the API in `GET_LIST`.

That is the reason I've called the API in the component and then decided to pass the data in props to the `[List][1]` component.

Answer (score -1):

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#actions

You can use the below actions props to control and change the flow/data

```
const PostActions = ({
    bulkActions,
    basePath,
    currentSort,
    displayedFilters,
    exporter,
    filters,
    filterValues,
    onUnselectItems,
    resource,
    selectedIds,
    showFilter,
    total
}) => (
    <CardActions>
        {bulkActions && React.cloneElement(bulkActions, {
            basePath,
            filterValues,
            resource,
            selectedIds,
            onUnselectItems,
        })}
        {filters && React.cloneElement(filters, {
            resource,
            showFilter,
            displayedFilters,
            filterValues,
            context: 'button',
        }) }
        <CreateButton basePath={basePath} />
        <ExportButton
            disabled={total === 0}
            resource={resource}
            sort={currentSort}
            filter={filterValues}
            exporter={exporter}
        />
        <RefreshButton />
        {/* Add your custom actions */}
        <Button color="primary" onClick={customAction}>Custom Action</Button>
    </CardActions>
);

export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} actions={<PostActions />}>
        ...
    </List>
);
```